# Setting empty elements of array as NULL

Tags: php

I get an array with a lot of elements.

Those elements might be `$data[0] = ""`

I want to set the data to `NULL` if this is the case, however since it will be done pretty often, I wonder if there is a way to make `""` `NULL` by default instead of a loop looking for `""`.

Comment: give a sample or array set;

Comment: what if a value is `0` or `"0"` or `[]`(empty array) ? Consider processing empty values while constructing an array

Comment: it can be achieved with a set of functions, but it'll be overcomplicated for such simple task. Regular `foreach` loop would be enough

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    <?php

    $array = [
        '',
        '0',
        '1'
    ];
    $nullArray = array_fill(0, 3, null);
    $filter = array_filter($array);
    var_dump($filter + $nullArray);
```